# Pandas in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am posting this and hoping I will get a convincing answer.
df is my dataframe. I want to know what is being passed to min_max in apply function. When I print row inside min_max I don't get a dataframe same as I get outside it

```
import numpy as np
    def min_max(row):
        print(row)
        print()
        data = row[['POPESTIMATE2010',
                    'POPESTIMATE2011',
                    'POPESTIMATE2012',
                    'POPESTIMATE2013',
                    'POPESTIMATE2014',
                    'POPESTIMATE2015']]
        return pd.Series({'min': np.min(data), 'max': np.max(data)})

    df.apply(min_max, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

df.apply simply calls/invokes provided function, in your case min_max function for each objects in input axis. From [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) of apply function, axis=1 represents row wise operation and axis=0 represents column wise operation

Thus, in your case, it will invoke min_max function for each row of dataframe.
For further elaboration.

```
def print_funt(row):
    pdb.set_trace()
    print(row)


df = pd.DataFrame({'Temp1':[62,62,50,62,50,62,62],
                   'Temp2':[66,66,69,66,69,66,66],
                   'Temp3':[52,62,52,62,52,62,52],
                   'Target':[0.24,0.28,0.25,0.28,0.25,0.28,0.24]})


print(df)
df.apply(print_funt, axis=1)
```

[output of apply function at first iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jw8L.jpg)